# why i am getting "Inconsistent ending lines" warning window while executing sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i try to execute a sql script it gives an warning window that

> "line endings in the following file are inconsistent. Do you want to
>   normalize it?".

I just want to know why i am getting this and how can i fix it permanently.please help.

Comment: You are using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, i am using Microsoft sql server

Comment: I have seen this when I've opened an old .sql file that was probably generated in an older version of SSMS than the one I am currently using.  If I click "yes" to normalize and save the file, I never get the warning again for that file.

Answer (score 9):

Because you have some lines ended with a CR/LF pair, and some lines ending with just a CR or LF (basically mixing Apple, Unix, and Windows conventions somehow).  If you're copying and pasting from one editor into MSSMS, it could be that editor handles line-endings differently.  You should pretty much just normalize them when it happens.  To fix it permanently, you'll have to figure out where the mixed line-endings are coming from (most likely from your copy/paste source).