# Flyway getting rid of my comments - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, flyway

I have a very simple procedure with comments. Example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    -- Single line comment
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT GETDATE();
END
GO
```

The script is saved as encoded UTF-8.

When I migrate this with flyway (successfully) and later check it through the management studio, I see that the multi-line comment is stripped off. Also when viewing the flyway migrated procedure SSMS complains about 'Inconsistent Line Endings'. What am I missing here?

Comment: move the comment below CREATE PROCEDURE - for SSMS this helps - not sure if it helps when doing your migration. Inconsistent Line endings means some end on `\n` and some on `\r\n` mixing windows/linux style line ends

Comment: Ok, you are right, the comments are detected after the CREATE PROCEDURE. Thanks. How can I avoid the line ending problem? I am just scripting the procedure in SSMS and saving the file.

Comment: From experience such comments could be useless. Better to track changes in repository like `SVN/GIT`.

Comment: @lad2025 a history of comment is kindof useless I agree - a documentation of the intent of this procedure, a date of creation and the author could be very valuable especially if you have procs with complicated cursors that span some lines

Comment: @lad2025 We are not tracking the changes in the comments. It's just a way to keep track of author or the last person who edited, etc. I do agree that most of this could be done through git.

Answer (score 1):

Glad that moving the comment down helped you - as for your 2nd problem:

[why i am getting "Inconsistent ending lines" warning window while executing sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786710/why-i-am-getting-inconsistent-ending-lines-warning-window-while-executing-sql)

Quintessence: find what corrupts it and fix it ;o)

**Manually**

If you have notepad++ you can clean your scripts by opening them, then Edit/EOL Conversion/ and choose what EOLs you want

**kindof automatic**

see [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings) 
--> be careful with the MORE thing, it kills your file if you use it inplace (inputfile=outputfile)