# Edit .sql files with R

Tags: sql, r, newline

I'm trying to take a SQL file, modify it using R and then save it again in another location. As part of this process, I don't want to modify the formatting.

I've tried using the following (I've stripped the transformation step because it's irrelevant here):

```
query <- readChar(location, file.info(location)$size)
writeLines(query, file.path(folder$new, script))
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the query seems to double all new lines and when I open the newly created .sql file, I get the warning message "The line endings in the following file are not consistent. Do you want to normalize the line endings?"

I've found this question which suggests that it's a combination or CR/LF issues ([why i am getting "Inconsistent ending lines" warning window while executing sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786710/why-i-am-getting-inconsistent-ending-lines-warning-window-while-executing-sql)), but I don't know how to fix/prevent them.

Has anyone had any success in this area? Perhaps a better way of reading .sql files?

Comment: I can confirm this too on Windows. Interesting.

Comment: Did you read the docs pages on [writeLines](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/writeLines) especially regarding line endings?

Comment: Indeed, it seems to discuss this and suggests `?writeChar` might be helpful.